# http server validation

Tags: ruby, apache

I finish a litle http server, writing from scratch. 
I would like to be sure that my imlementation is conforme to the HTTP specifications.
W3C give us tools for HTML/XML conformance, but i see nothing for http protocole and
specialy for the server part.

Is there a test tool for verify that ?

(no secret :  http://raubarede.homelinux.org/ruby/local/PicoWebServer )

Answer (score 0):

You could always try and extract the comprehensive unit tests from Mongrel (http://github.com/mongrel/mongrel/) which are designed to test HTTP handling.