# Http 1.1 protocol validation

Tags: web-services, http

Is there any service or library that can validate an http1.1 server?

I implemented a simple http server, and over a year or so I've been extending it as I need to such that I've got a pretty complete and functional http1.1 web/app server.

As a practical matter it works really well - e.g. it seems to serve things robustly to all the browsers I've tried, cUrl etc, but there are a million corner cases when you read the specs for http1.1. I'm sure I have all kinds of odd gremlins in there.

Is there a service that can make http requests to a server to validate the protocol, or a library that does this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729509/http-server-validation.

Comment: No answers over there either. They suggest using the test code from Mongrel. I looked it over - the tests are super basic. I need stuff like making sure say that say a matrix of features like compression, conditional headers, range requests and cache headers all work in different cobinations.

Comment: @marcin: my preference would have been a c/c++ lib.

Comment: This isn't a language-specific issue. You're going to have to deal with the fact not everything exists in every language.

Answer (score 1):

Jigsaw is the W3C's reference implementation of HTTP 1.1 http://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/

You can probably use that to compare responses between your server and Jigsaw. If it doesn't have its own blackbox test suite, you might have to go through the RFC and create your own suite.

There are further resources here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Forum/#Sample

This includes a reference to at least one HTTP 1.1 client library. You might use that, or any other one with good compliance to build your own black box tests.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything comprehensive, but [REDbot](http://redbot.org/) is useful for testing some of the subtleties of HTTP caching.